# How to check if prototype functions are different

Tags: javascript, comparison, prototype

Is there a way to check if functions are different even though they come from same prototype? 
I am asking this because I need to store functions in an array and when I try to remove one of them it removes all functions because prototypes are the same.

For example in the code below program will return true when comparing two functions.

```js
var Car = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

Car.prototype.checkLights = function() {
  // some calculation...
};

var Nissan = new Car('nissan');
var Toyota = new Car('toyota');

// this will return true even though functions came from different objects
console.log(Nissan.checkLights === Toyota.checkLights)
```

Comment: Why do you need to run this check `Nissan.checkLights === Toyota.checkLights`?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). That equality will always return true. So, how are you adding and removing from the array that is causing it to remove all the references

Comment: You cannot differentiate those functions if you store it in the prototype, because that's the point of prototypes, the prototype is the exact same for both objects. It also means that if you remove one function for one this way, it will be removed from all instances

Comment: Well it's kind of the whole point of a prototype, it's shared among objects.  What is it your trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Kaddath I thought so :(  I asked because there is a lot of code to change if there is no way to check if functions came from different objects. thx though

Comment: `var Nissan = new Car('nissan');`  Slightly OT, but `var Nissan`, using coding standards is better written as `var nissan = new Car('nissan');`  .Because if another coder, or maybe even yourself in the future look at this code, you might think `Nissan` is meant to be a constructor and not an object instance.

Comment: @royalBlue but *it shouldn't matter* where they came from. If you store a reference to `Nissan.checkLights` you have two options - that relies on `this` and so on the object you'd normally execute it on (`Nissan`) but you lose that context and that function reference is now useless as it would *at best* give you the wrong result if executed. It can also return an error. If it *doesn't* rely on `this`, then it's rather useless to compare them - any two would behave identically if executed and there is no meaningful difference where they came from.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on your requirement (by seeing your code), But both your new objects `Nissan` and `Toyota` are instances of `Car` with shared `prototype` object.

This means, whatever you change in one's prototype [function/property] that will get reflected in other object.

If you want them to behave independently then you can do like this:-

### Member functions

```js
    var Car = function(name) {
        this.name = name;

        // add as member function
        this.checkLights = function(){
            // some calculation...
        };
    };

    var Nissan = new Car('nissan');
    var Toyota = new Car('toyota');

    console.log(Nissan.checkLights === Toyota.checkLights); // false
```

> Now, I would highly advise against it unless you have a very specific case, this will create a new instance of `checkLights()` function every time you run constructor of `Car`

Comment: @royalBlue: For specific answer, Let me what you want to achieve with that array ?